# How to clone object with different specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I Want to split objects by assessment unit ids.

I have this

```
{ 
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"asessment_units[]": ["2", "4", "5","8"]
}
```

and from this object I want four objects (because I have 4 elements in the assessment unit).

1 st object

```
{ 
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"asessment_units[]": ["2"]
}
```

2nd object

```
{ 
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"asessment_units[]": ["4"]
}
```

3rd object

```
{ 
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"asessment_units[]": ["5"]
}
```

4th object

```
{ 
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"asessment_units[]": ["8"]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const obj = {
  name: "test",
  description: "test",
  "asessment_units[]": ["2", "4", "5", "8"],
};
const splitObjs = obj["asessment_units[]"].map(unit =>
  Object.assign({}, obj, {
    "asessment_units[]": [unit],
  })
);
console.log(splitObjs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` on `asessment_units[]` to achieve the transformation. Spread `name` and `description` keys of the object as they are common and insert respective value in an array inside the callback of `map`.

```
const obj = { 
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
   "asessment_units[]": ["2", "4", "5","8"]


}

 const res = obj['asessment_units[]'].map((val,index)=>{

   return {...obj, ['asessment_units[]'] : [val]}
})
```